# What happens with references to window when we close it and how to prevent this memory leakage?

Tags: java, design-patterns, model-view-controller, memory-leaks

I'm interested in the issue of preventing memory leakages in long life java applications. So let's say we create a window for each user in some server side application. We have someone who is specifically develops this window. The developer of this window does something at `onClose()`, but the references to this window are still there. Which means that if the end user of that window has put some 1MB image into this window via some reference, then for 1000 users we'll have 1GB un-freed memory.

What is the common way (maybe some design pattern) to prevent such memory leakage in long life applications?

I'm reading [this article in JavaWorld](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077581/learn-java/java-tip-79--interact-with-garbage-collector-to-avoid-memory-leaks.html) and I see that in the end it solves something that is related to references inside listeners. I don't understand the connection of it to this problem.

I do understand that we can simply create an external listeners which'll put null into all of the references to that window once it is closed, however I don't think it's the best solution (e.g. think of what happens when someone create a reference and forgets to add such a listener!).

Comment: I'm not sure what creating windows on a server side application entails. Usually these sort of issues are either solved by ensuring you control references and kill them in listeners, or by using weak references. In this particular case, with vague details and no code, there's no more specific answer.

Comment: Shall we just rely on whoever stores a reference that he'll create a listener? If so, I really hope that someone will develop one day a design pattern to deal with it.

Comment: As I said, usually you write the API so that you control the references. Without more information we cannot help you.

Comment: But how to create such API? Maybe I'm coming out of a wrong point of view, but as for me - there must be some design patter/s people usually use to take care of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what type of Window in a server context you mean. But typically you need to ensure there is no reference anymore (i.e. you do not store it in a session object).

In addition to that you can make the window.close() method null all fields. So in case the references to the Window is not nulled in time, at least the content can be garbage collected early.

In a MVC your controller might be bound to a (HTTP) session, so you need to make sure the reference is nulled:

```
class Controller {
  Window window;
  void closeWindow() {
    window.close(); // drops image (optional)
    window = null;  // frees object reference
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for willing to help, but it's a word by word cover of what I said in the last paragraph.

Comment: But to make it sure: I am not saying you should use a delegate wrapper which can drop the reference. I am saying that the client code needs to null the reference (or drop the object containing the reference). In a web app you normally have no problem as you hold references only in request method or session.

Comment: Wow, that was a helpful comment :-) . So now the naswer of Boris from the above comment also makes sense to me. Thanks!